# Ubuntu 22.04 on Hyper-V with static ip

Tags: hyper-v, static-ip, ubuntu-22.04

I set up a Ubuntu 22.04 server on a Hyper-V and then installed nginx. In the Hyper-V manager I created a Virtual Switch with an "Internal Network" connection type. I then went to Network Connections and set the IP Address consistent with my internal network.

I immediately see that the vEthernet connection is labeled "Unidentified Network". I changed the submask but still not luck. My goal is to forward traffic from the internet to this VM so having the static IP is important. How can I fix the network issue?

Comment: Internal network is "internal" to the Hyper-V host, you can't get any access to the "external" network, which is your physical LAN and Internet.  You need to create an external switch connected to one of your NICs for your VM to see outside of the Hyper-V host.

Comment: If you want NAT (Internal Switch) then use DHCP. If you wish a Static IP, make a New External Switch in Hyper-V.  Shut down Guest, use Hyper-V to give Guest the External Swittch and make the IP static.